# Is there a way to abort the processing of a Routing Slip without throwing an Exception?

Tags: apache-camel

I have a routing slip that has a handful of steps. I want to be able to include steps that perform some validation that can short-circuit the routing slip if needed.

I have:

```
from("direct:Start")
  .setHeader(header("RoutingSlip", config::getRoutingSlip)
  .doTry()
    .routingSlip(header("RoutingSlip"))
  .doEndTry()
    .doCatch(ValidationException.class)
      .log("Validation failed!")
  .end()
```

Is this the best way to do this?

The fact that there is a stacktrace being logged makes me question if this is the right way to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try to replace your raising exception code by setting
the property Exchange.ROUTE_STOP to true
ie.
`exchange.setProperty(Exchange.ROUTE_STOP, Boolean.TRUE);`

Comment: That looks more elegant. However, `ROUTE_STOP` is marked as deprecated. (see https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/camel-3x-upgrade-guide-3_1.html#_exchange_route_stop) So `exchange.setRouteStop(true);`.

Thanks for the pointer. :)